# Rebuilding bindings on Change of the data passed to ViewModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

This is the scenario. I want to update the name when change is clicked. The  data I am referring here represents ajax data  in the real code. Hope this makes clear.

Here is my:

**Java script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = "bipin";
  $("#ram").click(function() {
    data = "hari";

  });
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
});


function ViewModel(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
}
```

**And HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
  <button id="ram">change</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use observable containers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = ko.observable("bipin");
  $("#ram").click(function() {
    data("hari");
  });
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
});

function ViewModel(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
}
```

Comment: You should use observables for objects, that will be bound to the markup. You can check patched jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4mtqurc3/4/

Comment: I not allowed to change the data format. It is received through server. I have explained in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/52qyb2qd/1/

Comment: I've updated your fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/52qyb2qd/2/). You can use ko.computed: "self.name = ko.computed(function() { return name().dict.end; });". Also you can use Knockout mapping plugin (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) co create model with observable properties from received JSON.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not the knockout way. Take a look at their [learning center](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

To answer your question, here is the right way do acheive it :

```js
function ViewModel () {
  var self = this;
  
  self.name = ko.observable('John');
  
  self.changeName = function () {
    self.name('Jessica');  
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h1>Name :</h1>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
<button data-bind="click: changeName">Click me</button>
```